# How to polymorphic call a method from a stack of two different child types

Tags: java, stack, overriding, overloading, abstract-class

I have 4 separate classes UI, Parent, child1 and child2.
I have a parent stack containing both child1 and child2.
I'm trying to call a method when iterating through the stack that changes depending on whether it is of type child1 or child2.

I've tried creating an abstract method in parent and overriding the method in child1 and child2 but it says method does not override or implement from super type.

I've tried to make a public empty method in parent and override the methods in each child case but when I call the method from main in UI it calls the empty method.

I found a workaround by looking at instanceof in the stack which worked but I ran into issues later in the program trying to save/load data. Please see rough code below and any questions let me know.

```
public abstract class parent {

    public void addToPuzzle(){};

}

public class child1 extends parent {

    public void addToPuzzle(abc)
}


public class child2 extends parent {

    public void addToPuzzle(wxyz)
}

public class ui{

    public void undoMove(){
        for(parent p : oldStack){
            p.addToPuzzle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `method(someargument)` in a sub-class doesn't override `method()` in the superclass; the argument lists have to match.

Comment: The function `addToPuzzle` in the parent doesn't have any argument. But it seems like `addToPuzzle` takes argument in the child classes, that's why the function is not overriding.

The code also looks confusing to me as you have UserEntry class, how is it related to parent. Also you have not mentioned the argument type in functions `addToPuzzle(wxyz)` and `public void addToPuzzle(abc)`

Comment: @DeepakPatankar sorry the user entry should be parent. For each p in the parent stack I want to call addToPuzzle but it should change depending on if it is child1 or child2

Answer (score 0):

The method in the parent class is `public void addToPuzzle()`, whereas the child class has a different function which takes an argument `public void addToPuzzle(abc)`.

A child class will override the method of a parent class when the following conditions are satisfied:

- The method must have the same name as in the parent class.
- The method must have the same parameters as in the parent class.
- There must be an IS-A relationship (inheritance).

Comment: Is there another way that isn't overriding to call the method when the methods in the child class have different parameters?

Comment: Please update the addToPuzzle function of child 1and child 2, this will give me more idea about the problem.